# "Segmentation fault" error message for simple list in c

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void printList(struct node *head);

int main() {
    struct node* head;
    head->data =10;
    head->next = NULL;
    printList(head);    
}


void printList(struct node *head){
    struct node *ptr = head;
    if (ptr->next = NULL){
        printf("list is empty");
    }
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%d", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

I'm try to implement a simple list structure, but I am getting a segmentation error.

Any clues to why?

Comment: `head->data = 10;` : ask yourself the question: where does `head` point to? Did you read the chapter dealing with pointers and dynamic memory allocation in your learning material?

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code

1. In main function, the `head` pointer is not initialized. You need to allocate memory for the object it will point to.

```
struct node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

2. In printList function, if statement using '=' assignment operator instead of '==' comparison operator

```
if (ptr->next == NULL){
    printf("list is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems here.
Check better about how pointers works in c.

When you write something like this  `struct node* head;` you only added an address memory pointing to another undefined zone of space.
So, in order to generate something you should *alloc* some memory in it before accessing that zone of memory and setting data.

Another problem is the first if condition in printList function that should have '==' instead of '='